# Query server for unused procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to write a query to find all procedures in the database that are not in use.

I have one piece of code that lists all the procedures in the database:

```
SELECT p.name AS 'SP Name'
FROM sys.procedures AS p
WHERE p.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY p.name
```

I have also another piece of code that checks if an expression is in use anywhere in the existing procedures:

```
declare @expression nvarchar(100) = '%sp_myProcedure%'

SELECT DISTINCT 
    o.name AS Object_Name,
    o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
    ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like @expression
```

Now I'd like to combine both. First get the list of all procedures, than run it through the code in the second snippet. Finally, list those that returned no results (or technically, those that returned one result because the name of the procedure will always occur in the definition of the procedure).

For now I create the list (first snippet) and check if it's accessed anywhere (second snippet) but I do it manually. How can I automate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`. The `APPLY` operator allows you to invoke a table-valued function for each row returned by an outer table expression of a query.

You can try this:

```
SELECT P.name AS 'SP Name'
             ,TU.Object_Name
FROM sys.procedures AS P
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT O.name AS Object_Name
                            ,O.type_desc
             FROM sys.sql_modules AS M
             INNER JOIN sys.objects AS O
                ON M.object_id = O.object_id
             WHERE M.definition LIKE '%' + P.name + '%') AS TU
WHERE P.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY P.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have the first query's results iterated through on the second query, you can create an alias and feed it through. Eg:

```
;with prc_names as (SELECT p.name AS sp_name
FROM sys.procedures AS p
WHERE p.is_ms_shipped = 0)

SELECT  
p.sp_name as 'SP Name',
o.name AS Object_Name,
o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m, prc_names p 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like p.sp_name
group by p.sp_name, o.name, o.type_desc
order by p.sp_name
```

Or something similar. You can also stick a count on the second select clause if you want the numbers (as I'd imagine this will return a lot of results).

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of only unused procedures I slightly modified **king.code**'s (very helpful) solution:

```
-- List only unused procedures
SELECT v.SP_Name FROM 
    (SELECT P.name AS SP_Name ,TU.Object_Name
    FROM sys.procedures AS P
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT O.name AS Object_Name
                                ,O.type_desc
                 FROM sys.sql_modules AS M
                 INNER JOIN sys.objects AS O
                     ON M.object_id = O.object_id
                 WHERE M.definition LIKE '%' + P.name + '%') AS TU
    WHERE P.is_ms_shipped = 0) v
GROUP BY v.SP_Name 
HAVING COUNT(v.SP_Name) <= 1
```

If the name of the procedure occurs once it's only in procedure declaration - so there are no other references to this procedure in the database.